How can I move a string, and its slices into a closure safely?
I am trying to create a 'static closure that moves in slices of a string, a Vec<&str> to be exact.
My initial attempt was something like:
fn main() {
    let sentence = "Foo to the bar".to_string();
    let my_closure = get_closure(sentence);
    my_closure();
}

fn get_closure(sentence: String) -> impl Fn() {
    // Heap allocation.
    let words: Vec<String> = sentence.split_whitespace().map(ToString::to_string).collect();
    move || {
        for word in &words {
            word.as_bytes().iter().map(|n| *n as usize).sum::<usize>();
        }
    }
}

This performed pretty well, however it has the downside of creating new String's which means more heap allocation.
My next solution was to use unsafe and transmute in order to extend the lifetime of words whilst still moving in the string. This solution works, whilst only creating a Vec of slices, which is smaller than copying each word.
fn main() {
    let sentence = "Foo to the bar".to_string();
    let my_closure = get_closure(sentence);
    my_closure();
}

fn get_closure(sentence: String) -> impl Fn() {
    let words: Vec<&'static str> = unsafe { 
        std::mem::transmute(sentence.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>()) 
    };
    move || {
        let _mover = &sentence;
        for word in &words {
            word.as_bytes().iter().map(|n| *n as usize).sum::<usize>();
        }
    }
}

This worked as intended without any issues, however I still have a few problems:

Is there a cleaner way to do this without more heap allocations (ideally without using unsafe, but I doubt it)?
Is the last solution mentioned safe?

Just for a bit of context, the actual use case for is this is in a hotspot, so the reason I want to do this, is to avoid the splitting on every call. The practical solution would be to move clone the splits and store a Vec<String> and use that in the closure. That does involve a few extra allocations compared to the unsafe version since we must allocate a new string for each word seperated by a whitespace, however it is solution worth mentioning.
I wrote a test to see the difference between using unsafe and and cloning the String into a Vec. Feel free to take a look:
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};

fn get_closure_unsafe(sentence: String) -> impl Fn(usize) {
    let words: Vec<&'static str> =
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(sentence.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>()) };
    move |_: usize| {
        let _mover = &sentence; 
        for word in &words {
            word.as_bytes().iter().map(|n| *n as usize).sum::<usize>();
        }
    }
}

fn get_closure_safe(sentence: String) -> impl Fn(usize) {
    let words: Vec<String> = sentence
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(ToString::to_string)
        .collect();
    move |_: usize| {
        for word in &words {
            word.as_bytes().iter().map(|n| *n as usize).sum::<usize>();
        }
    }
}

fn bench_fibs(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("Str split");
    let sentence = "Foo to the bar".to_string();
    let safe_closure = get_closure_safe(sentence.clone());
    group.bench_function("safe", |b| b.iter(|| safe_closure(black_box(1))));

    let unsafe_closure = get_closure_unsafe(sentence);
    group.bench_function("unsafe", |b| b.iter(|| unsafe_closure(black_box(1))));
    group.finish();
}

criterion_group!(comparison, bench_fibs);
criterion_main!(comparison);

Results:
Str split/safe          time:   [214.28 ps 214.48 ps 214.73 ps]
                        change: [-1.4155% -1.0571% -0.7363%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Change within noise threshold.
Found 14 outliers among 100 measurements (14.00%)
  4 (4.00%) high mild
  10 (10.00%) high severe
Str split/unsafe        time:   [214.12 ps 214.35 ps 214.82 ps]
                        change: [-0.5763% -0.4318% -0.2713%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Change within noise threshold.
Found 12 outliers among 100 measurements (12.00%)
  7 (7.00%) high mild
  5 (5.00%) high severe


Your example benchmark panics in debug mode because summing the bytes within "Foo" overflows 255.

OnceCell might be an option if you just want to avoid the computation overhead.

Currently updating the question. Sorry for that.

You're creating a self referential struct (the closure), see Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct? how you can and why it's difficult.

Yes, I am aware that it can be quite tricky. I think my last solution does overcome it since we move the string in the closure, and then only read from it which should make the slices valid (meaning the underlying str's should stay where they are), but I am not super confident on the safety side of it.

I think it's relying on an assumption that is not codified yet, (the assumption that moving String doesn't invalidate references to the data) but it would surprise me if it would ever not hold.

@cafce25: For Box not String but I'd assume the same applies, Considerations for unsafe code explicitly says "Using raw pointers derived from a box after that box has been ... moved ... is not allowed". Perhaps that's too loosely worded, however.  Miri certainly isn't complaining, which somewhat surprised me as I assumed it'd violate stacked borrows.

Is the returned closure a hotspot or the closure creation? The closures runtime will be equivalent, as benchmarking shows (it can be worse if you have many of them, because of cache non-locality). Closure creation, however, which you don't benchmark, will be slower indeed.

It's tricky since if you move both an object and its borrows into a closure, that means your closure object needs to be self-referencing.
One way to solve this in a safe manner is to use a self-reference library like ouroboros:
use ouroboros::self_referencing;

fn main() {
    let sentence = "Foo to the bar".to_string();
    let my_closure = get_closure(sentence);
    my_closure();
}

#[self_referencing]
struct ClosureData {
    pub sentence: String,

    #[borrows(sentence)]
    #[covariant]
    pub words: Vec<&'this str>,
}

fn get_closure(sentence: String) -> impl Fn() {
    let closure_data = ClosureDataBuilder {
        sentence,
        words_builder: |sentence| sentence.split_whitespace().collect(),
    }.build();

    // now you can move closure_data
    move || {
        let _ = closure_data.borrow_sentence();  // the String is accessible
        for word in closure_data.borrow_words() {
            println!("{word}");
        }
    }
}


The _mover variable is not needed now, the sencence is moved automatically inside closure_data.

Note that this does require heap allocation (although just one), something that airblast wishes to not have.

@rodrigo Right, thanks. I left it there to demonstrate accessing the string. I just changed it to let _ = to make it clearer.

“Since String is just a reference to the underlying str” — it's a reference in the sense that it stores a pointer to str, but it is very much an owned (and more importantly Drop) value, and once dropped its underlying str is freed. You can just move the declaration of words into the closure and get rid of other “move hacks”.
fn get_closure(sentence: String) -> impl Fn() {
    move || {
        let words: Vec<&str> = sentence.split_whitespace().collect();
        for word in &words {
            println!("{word}");
        }
    }
}

If you want to avoid creating words on every call, just take sentence by reference:
fn get_closure<'a>(sentence: &'a str) -> impl 'a + Fn() {
    let words: Vec<&str> = sentence.split_whitespace().collect();

    move || {
        for word in &words {
            println!("{word}");
        }
    }
}


They offer that as an alternative themselves, but say they want to avoid the split_whitespace overhead on every call of the returned closure.

I also found a much much better approach that doesnt involve unsafe but has other drawbacks. I will edit the post shortly.

As mentioned in the question the return value must have a 'static lifetime, if that wasn't the case, the last solution you wrote would be a completely valid solution.

I can make the return value of the first function 'static + Fn() without any further modification. sentence is moved into the closure, where it lives indefinitely (since String: 'static).

@airblast: "the return value must have a 'static lifetime" — why?  If because the closure needs to remain available for the remainder of the program's lifetime, you could just use String::leak to get a &'static str; if the closure might be dropped before the end of the program's lifetime, what is the issue with tying it to such lifetime by borrowing from the String?

I don't need a &'static str, I need a 'static + impl Fn(..) -> .., in another way to explain: A fully owned closure. The goal isn't to get a static str from a String, it's just a side effect in the solutions of my question. That being said, using String::leak would cause a memory leak when the closure is dropped, and 'static lifetime doesn't strictly mean it will live until the program is closed.
